# PHP shell_exec can't change to root directory

Tags: php, shell-exec

i want to do a command to run ansible on linux terminal via web interface with php shell exec. My web interface is in `/var/www/html` while my ansible playbook is in `/root/git/ansible`. Here is the directory structure of my linux :

```
/
├── var
│   └── www
│       └── html
│           └── index.php
└── root
    └── git
        └── ansible
            └── ansible-playbook.yml
```

as you can see, my php script in index.php so the working directory is in `/var/www/html`. To run ansible-playbook.yml, i have to change the working directory to /root/git/ansible. However, I can't access /root and can only be on /var.

When i tried `shell_exec('cd ; pwd');` the output will be the parent directory which is `/var/www` . I also tried the `shell_exec('cd .. ; cd .. ; cd .. ; cd root/git/ansible ; pwd);` expecting to get `/root/git/ansible` as result, but i got `/` instead which seems like the `cd root/git/ansible` command is ignored. I also tried the `chdir()` before executing shell_exec() but the result is the same. I still can't change to root directory.

I read somewhere that it is for security concerns, but is there a possible way to do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does your www user have access to the requested path? If you are not in the testing environment, I would suggest not to.

Comment: Add a `set -xe` in the beginning, then you will immediately be notified when one of the commands fails.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can skip all the `cd ..;` and just do: `cd /root/...` (with the initial `/` that indicates the top folder)

Comment: I suggest putting the file you need somewhere that the www user is able to access without elevated privileges